# UIPageControl does not appear to always change upon scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have a UIPageViewController where i've placed a UIPageControl. This seem to work most of the time when i scroll, however sometimes it does not change the current selected Page. What could trigger this behaviour?

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! WalkthroughViewController

    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    self.pageControl.currentPage = index

    if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound)

    {

        return nil



    }



    index--

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let vc = viewController as! WalkthroughViewController

    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    self.pageControl.currentPage = index


    if (index == NSNotFound)

    {

        return nil

    }



    index++



    if (index == self.pageTitles.count)

    {

        return nil

    }



    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> UIViewController? {

    if ((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {

        return WalkthroughViewController()

    }


    let pageContentViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WalkthroughViewController") as! WalkthroughViewController
    pageContentViewController.titleText = pageTitles[index] as String
    pageContentViewController.subText = pageSubTitles[index] as String
    pageContentViewController.imageText = pageImages[index] as String
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

    return pageContentViewController
}
```

Comment: Check out this method.pageViewController:(UIPageViewController * )pageViewController
        didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished
   previousViewControllers:(NSArray * )previousViewControllers
       transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed

Answer (score 0):

Probably the main point to learn about the UIPageViewControl is that tracking which page you are on with an int does not work. Will never work. Trying to make it work will make you crazy.

Given a view controller you have to get the index, each time, by comparing it to the ones you have.

If you read the Apple sample code you will see that. It's really confusing and this is, by all accounts, one of the weaker Cocoa components.

Solution: let's say you have a page control and you have 5 different controllers you are paging through. When the framework asks for the before or after controller, it passes you the current controller. You should take that and loop through the ones you have to find the index of the current one in your collection, then simply either add or subtract one (after/before) and return the controller at that index. That simple.

Part of the reason that it's done this way is that you might not want to have a different controller for each page. For instance, you might have the same controller that you are just sticking different things into. In that case, you can just keep altering subcomponents in a single component then returning that same component after having altered its contents.

Comment: So what do you recommend ?

Comment: issue is that i only have 1 viewContoller, where the content just changes

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Still, this answer holds the solution. Suppose your walkthrough is a bunch of Posts (a class with the fields you are showing). You need to have a way to tell which post you are on, given the current controller that was passed to you. Period. That's the answer. So let's say for instance that your controller has a currrentPostId. You would pull that off of there, then loop through your posts (or use an NSPredicate) and find the one with that id, then return either the prior or next one.